# Crear archivo y descargarlo

Tags: javascript, html5

Estuve buscando como hacer para poder tomar una información, transformarla a en un archivo y este descargarlo, pude hacerlo pero mi problema radica en que no puedo seleccionar DONDE quiero guardarlo, siempre por defecto está en la carpeta descargas. Ahora lo raro de mi función es que esta acepta 2 parámetros

```
function download (parametro1, parámetro2)
```

al momento de solo pasarle UN parámetro esta SI me pregunta donde quiero descargar el archivo, pero al pasarle los 2 parámetros que es lo que debería hacer, me lo descarga directamente en la carpeta "descargas

Esta es mi función:

```
 function download2(name, feature) {
  var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([feature], { type: 'text/plain' });
  var fileNameToSaveAs = name + ".feature";
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  console.log(downloadLink)
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

Esto solamente es la función onclick del boton, cuando la llamo de esta manera SI me aparece la ventana de seleccion de descarga

```
const btnD = document.querySelector("#btnDescargar")
btnD.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("clickee el boton")
  download2(contenido)
})
```

si llamo a la función de esta forma NO me permite seleccionar

```
download2("nombreArchivo",contenido)
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola, un pregunta jeje, que tiene que ver esta pregunta con node? ya que veo que hasta ahora solo hay browser API en tu código, estas trabajando con electrón?

Comment: Hola disculpa, la verdad agregue el tag solo porque estoy personalmente trabajando con back, lo quitare
pd: no, con react y js

Comment: La ubicación para guardar el archivo es una característica del navegador que no puedes modificar desde Javascript. Solo el propio usuario puede modificar este comportamiento cambiando la carpeta por defecto o haciendo que el navegador te permita elegir cada que se haga una descarga.

Comment: @Triby Si!!! eso mismo quiero hacer, quiero que al clickear el boton se me abran los directorios para que el elija donde quiere guardarlo!! Como puedo hacerlo en base a lo que tengo?
Como dije, SI lo hace pero solo cuando le paso 1 parámetro, al pasarle 2 no lo hace

Comment: @Programmer89, respuesta corta: No se puede. Respuesta larga: Lee nuevamente mi comentario anterior.

Comment: Consulta, si no se puede, porque si lo estoy pudiendo hacer con la funcion escrita arriba? Me llama la atención el como estoy forzando un comportamiento que no se puede naturalmente :S @Triby

Comment: Entonces hazlo sin enviar el segundo parámetro, seguramente te guardará un archivo vacío, pero al menos te permite seleccionar la ubicación.

Comment: Nop, me guarda el archivo con su información correcta, el tema es que el nombre es enorme y los nombres no siempres son iguales asi que es dificil forzar que agarre cierto largo de lo que está seteando, de todas maneras gracias por la ayuda, seguiré buscando

Comment: Porque no usas [downloadjs](http://danml.com/download.html)? Es mas fácil y está bien OP

Comment: Recuerda que para que puedas descargar un archivo y que te pregunte donde lo quieres guardar la funcion debe ejecutarse de acuerdo a un action performed, es decir, un evento que el usuario haya disparado usando sus perifericos (mouse, teclado, microfono), etc, si no se te abre o no te aparece el gestor de descargas seguramente sea porque no se ha realizado un action performed, por lo tanto el navegador bloqueara cualquier clase de descarga no autorizada, solucion?, mandar a llamar esa funcion usando un listener, en este caso puede ser por ejemplo el evento click. (se dispara con un periferico)

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford Gracias por la respuesta compa! No la había visto, veré que onda enseguioda, muchas gracias por comentar

Comment: @Riven muchas gracias por la ayuda, finalmente decidi porque agarre la dirección de descarga que el selecciono en su navegador por defecto. De todas maneras investigare a ver si aprendo como hacer el tema de los perifericos que comentas, que actualmente nisiquiera se me ocurre como.
Gracias!